# Не устанавливается текст в EditText, при повторном вызове фрагмента

Tags: android

У меня есть диалоговый фрагмент, создаю его в `onCreate` активности:

```
workWithDictionaries = new WorkWithDictionaries();
```

При нажатии на пункт в списке, я передаю сам список фрагменту и позицию нажатого пункта в фрагмент, а потом вызываю его:

```
workWithDictionaries.renameDictionary(position, mList);
workWithDictionaries.show(getFragmentManager(), "WorkWithDictionaries RENAME");
```

Когда открывается фрагмент, вызывается `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_work_with_dictionaries, null);

        (view.findViewById(R.id.work_with_dictionaries_button_1)).setOnClickListener(this);
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.work_with_dictionaries_editText_1);

        if (my_action == ACTION_RENAME) {
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "RENAME");
            mEditText.setText(mList.get(position).get(2));
            mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length());
        }

        return view;
    }
```

И я пытаюсь установить текст в `EditText`. При первом запуске, все проходит хорошо, текст вставляется, но когда я запускаю фрагмент во второй раз — текст остается с прошлого вызова (строки разные, я проверял... раз 20)! Но почему и как это исправить? Кстати, исправить ошибку помогало создание нового экземпляра фрагмента, но каждый раз создавать фрагмент...

Comment: P.S. Единственное, что я придумал — использовать диалоговую активность (активность с диалоговой темой).

Comment: Меня терзает смутное воспоминание, что этот вопрос вы уже задавали и уже сами себе также и отвечали...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я пришел к варианту создавать новый экземпляр, а сейчас создаю один `Intent` и вызываю его много раз. Но почему текст не заполнялся?

Comment: Ну, видать, диалог-фрагмент в фрагментМэнеджере сохраняется и ЕдитТекст со своим ИД в активити имеется... Ну и типа конфликты... ХЗ, это я гадаю, надо тестить, проверять. А текст, наверное, заполняется, просто его потом старый заменяет) Надо покопаться в способах восстановления состояний виджетов во фрагментах

Comment: А что такое my_action, и каково его значение во второй вызов фрагмента?

Comment: Я сначала задаю `my_action` методом, а уже, в зависимости от действия, фрагмент выбирает - добавлять новую запись или только обновить.